# Liquid simulation not working properly

Tags: animation

I am doing this project where the liquid is to fill this cup:

[image]

No matter what setting I choose, the flow is always the same:

[image]

These are exactly the settings I use:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe I did something wrong with my work. I hope someone knows how to fix this, because I spent many hours on this!

Comment: pls provide blend file, because fluid simulation is quite complex and just to show "some" settings here isn't enough. Just one example: the resolution value doesn't help at all for interpretation, if we don't have the information how big your object is....

Comment: As Chris says, hard to help without the file

Comment: sorry guys, Im a beginner, I didn`t know that the file was necessary. Here it goes (PS: Im brazillian, so some names are in portuguese)

Comment: I don`t know if there is anyway to upload the file here, so here is a google drive link with it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l51PzVQue-STicDqXb7g0EbfiLCrsPeO/view?usp=sharing